# How to Load the files in train folder under Health-News-dataset.zip file

Tags: python

The Health-News-Tweets.zip dataset contains tweets by different agencies like BBC Health, CBC Health, etc.

Each file contains tweets with ‘|’ as a separator
o ID | Timestamp | Tweet

[Dataset](https://github.com/ruchirm702/Datasets)

I tried some code :

```
import pyprind
import pandas as pd
import os


progBar = pyprind.ProgBar(3000) # initialize progress bar
df=pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe
for s in ('test','train'):
    path="./Health-News-Tweets/%s/%s" % (s) #file path
    for file in os.listdir(path):
        with open(os.path.join(path,file),'r') as infile:
            txt = infile.read()
            df= df.append([txt],ignore_index=True) #will append my content of particular text to the dataframe
            progBar.update() # updating progress bar 
            df.columns = ['ID','Timestamp','Tweet']
```

Error Message

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-ca9947fa4e2c> in <module>
      7 df=pd.DataFrame() # empty dataframe
      8 for s in ('test','train'):
----> 9     path="./Health-News-Tweets/%s/%s" % (s) #file path
     10     for file in os.listdir(path):
     11         with open(os.path.join(path,file),'r') as infile:

TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

I have to extract the tweets columns and peform preprocessing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to fix this line
`path="./Health-News-Tweets/%s/%s" % (s) #file path`

This line expects two strings since you have used two format specifiers `%s` but you supplied only one.

Example fix:

```
path="./Health-News-Tweets/%s" % (s) # file path
```

Comment: I tried like this `path="./Health-News-Tweets/train  %s %s" % (s,s)` but getting error `FileNotFoundError: [WinError 3] The system cannot find the path specified: './Health-News-Tweets/train test test` . I have provided the data if it could help

Comment: `train  %s %s`: do you really have whitespaces in the path? It's better to print out the path desired and then simply replace the strings with `%s`